# Randomise property name in Oozie workflow

Tags: oozie

I'd like to create a random 'staging' directory name as part of a larger workflow. Is it possible to randomise a configuration property's value for use in sub-worflows ?

Answer (score 1):

If the workflow ID is 'random' enough, you can use `${wf:id}`.

Comment: Its random, but pretty long and ugly. I would very much prefer something like a crc32, md5 or sha1 hash type of thing